# Can CloudKit be used to store data and send from one user to another?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, storekit

The data that I'm interested in sending is photos, videos, and contact information from one persons device to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudKit has private and public databases. If you store data in the private database, a different logged in user cannot access the data. If you store it in the public database, your app "owns" the data and can therefore choose to make it available to other users.

Comment: With iOS 10 there is now a shared database as well but that needs a few Moore weeks to become available.

Comment: Thanks Michael, is there a way to store data publicly.... but still have it password protected? Say User_A sends User_B a zipped file of photos. Can it be stored publicly, but be password protected?

Comment: As @RobertMasen says, you can wait for the iOS 10 update to get share functionality. Nevertheless, these are just cloud databases - the public one is only available to your app publicly (and you through the web). Your app can control access how ever it wants, password or no. You have to build it. Sharing in the iOS 10 update will make this a lot easier for you.

Comment: Thank you both! @Michael & Robert Masen

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CloudKit can do that all. The demo app for this CloudKit based helper library is a complete chat app: https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao